# Impossibility of improved upper bound for non-abundant sums?

Tags: number-theory, logic

I was doing [Project Euler problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23) and wondered about the following statement:

> By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

I am no number theorist and am not sure exactly what's meant by "analysis" here or what force "cannot" has in this claim. Is there an impossibility result behind this or is it just something we don't know how to do (yet)? The problem can trivially be solved by exhaustion of course.

Comment: The proof they mean that every sufficient large number is the sum of two abundant numbers itself only gives this number as a possibility to make "sufficiently large" concrete. Exhaustive search reveals that this result is not best. It would be interesting which is the actual largest number not being the sum of two abundant numbers.

Comment: Of course, a proof with a better bound could exist, but apparently is not known yet.

Comment: @Peter The problem *is* obviously recursively enumerable, so given reasonable logical apparatus it's calculable directly. My question is whether there's anything deeper to this. For example, are there limitative theorems in analytic number theory that tell us that certain techniques *cannot* produce a better upper bound even in principle? Put another way: is there something special about 28123?

Comment: The largest number which is not the sum of two abundant numbers is 20161 (if my python script works correctly), which is much lower than 28123. There are two cases: (a) Either there is an analysis argument that shows all n>=28123 are of this form but doesn't say anything about n<28123, or (b) The authors just wanted to have fun watching us squirm while trying to compute the largest such number. I personally think it is the latter.
By the way, in proofs of the form "X holds for all n>N", the number N doesn't need to be too special (we could replace N with 2N or 3N without affecting the proof).